# Android Scaling down Images

Tags: android

i have some large resolution images that I need to scale to fit every screen as a background, the images are size of 1800x2880 and I need them to scale down to every screeen without any stretching(they are illustrations).
What is the best approach?

Comment: It seems like you have two conflicting goals. If the ratios do not match you cannot, *inherently* make an image fit another ratio without stretching. Either you're going to have to crop some portion of it, show some empty space, or you're going to have to stretch it.

Comment: I already tried bitmapscaling to a sample to fit exactly, but some parts of the screen are left unfilled, so i used scaletype fitxy to stretch it. Is this the only way? I have tried to show that it is impossible to make an image like this not stretched on every android phone, but ive been force to "find a way"..

Comment: Draw a square. Draw a rectangle. Ask *them* to fit the rectangle in the square.

Comment: haha nice one.ill see what i can do with 9-patch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to read the android developer guide regarding [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and do exactly as they say there.

Anything else someone might answer you here will be simplification or copy or re-written with his own words of what said there.

**edit:**

regarding stretching the images you have two possible approaches:

- [create a 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) with your background so it can fill-in the last pixel (or fill in key areas of the image that can/should be filled in without changing the general aspect of it (it will depends on the content of the image)
- mark the imageView to use `CENTER_INSIDE`

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: i have read that page already, but i cant ensure that drawables for the several resolutions fill the whole screen whithout looking stretched; imagescale fitxy does exactly the opposite, should i put these images in drawable-nodpi?

Comment: stretching and number of DPI are different things. I'll update my answer with regarding stretching

Comment: ok, so basically use 9 patch to define what areas of the image are ok to stretch is it? going to try this out

Answer (score 0):

Image set on the xhdpi folder.In the XML you will be use fillparent.it will not be stretch.

Comment: the property fill_parent is obsolete and match_parent is its newer value